# Fastest way to find out if two sets overlap?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Obviously doing `std::set_intersection()` is a waste of time.
Isn't there a function in the algorithm header for doing exactly this?
`std::find_first_of()` is doing a linear search as far as I understand.

Comment: You've benchmarked that set_intersection was too slow for your needs?

Comment: The code for set_intersection is out there, freely available. Instead of storing the result in a set, abort at the first intersection, simple as that.

Comment: the question was not for (any) way to get this task done, but for the fastest way

Comment: I looked at the interface of std::set_intersection() and I understood that it could not possibly be the fastest way. This is why set::lower_bound() is faster than std::lower_bound() for a set.

Comment: `std::set_intersection()` is linear, and any fast solution to this problem will be linear.

Comment: Assuming sets are implemented as bitmaps (and in C/C++ they certainly should be), then sets overlap if A ^ B != A | B.

Comment: Show us example code.

Comment: @QuestionC: `any fast solution to this problem will be linear` - worst case. Now, how about average/expected …

Comment: @QuestionC How about the *best* case for 2 sets of size N? A best case is probably when two sets are equal. When an algorithm ends at the first hit, this will likely be O(1), but `std::set_intersection()` will still need O(n log n) to iterate over the inputs.

Answer (score 7):

This is a solution only for `std::set` (or multi).  A solution for map would require only a bit more work.

I try it 3 ways.

First, if one is far larger than the other, I simply look for all of the elements of one in the other.  Then vice versa.

The constant `100` is wrong theoretically.  It should be `k n lg m > m` for some k, not `100 n > m` for optimal big-O performance: but the constant factor is large, and 100>lg m, so really one should experiment.

If that isn't the case, we walk through each collection looking for collisions much like `set_intersection`.  Instead of just `++`, we use `.lower_bound` to try to skip through each list faster.

Note that if your list consists of interleaved elements (like `{1,3,7}` and `{0,2,4,6,8}`) this will be slower than just ++ by a logarithmic factor.

If the two sets "cross" each other less often, this can skip over large amounts of each set's contents.

Replace the `lower_bound` portion with a mere `++` if you want to compare the two behaviors.

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
bool sorted_has_overlap( Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs ) {
  if (lhs.empty() || rhs.empty()) return false;
  if (lhs.size() * 100 < rhs.size()) {
    for (auto&& x:lhs)
      if (rhs.find(x)!=rhs.end())
        return true;
    return false;
  }
  if (rhs.size() * 100 < lhs.size()) {
    for(auto&& x:rhs)
      if (lhs.find(x)!=lhs.end())
        return true;
    return false;
  }

  using std::begin; using std::end;

  auto lit = begin(lhs);
  auto lend = end(lhs);

  auto rit = begin(rhs);
  auto rend = end(rhs);

  while( lit != lend && rit != rend ) {
    if (*lit < *rit) {
      lit = lhs.lower_bound(*rit);
      continue;
    }
    if (*rit < *lit) {
      rit = rhs.lower_bound(*lit);
      continue;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

a sorted array could do the 3rd choice of algorithm and use `std::lower_bound` to do fast advance of the "other" container.  This has the advantage of using partial searches (which you cannot do fast in a `set`).  It will also behave poorly on "interleaved" elements (by a log n factor) compared to naive `++`.

The first two can also be done fast with sorted arrays, replacing method calls with calls to algorithms in `std`.  Such a transformation is basically mechanical.

An asymptotically optimal version on a sorted array would use a binary search biased towards finding lower bounds at the start of the list -- search at 1, 2, 4, 8, etc instead of at half, quarters, etc.  Note that this has the same lg(n) worst case, but is O(1) if the searched for element is *first* instead of O(lg(n)).  As that case (where the search advances less) means less global progress is made, optimizing the sub-algorithm for that case gives you a better global worst-case speed.

To get why, on "fast alternation" it wouldn't perform any worse than `++` -- the case where the next element is a sign swap takes O(1) operations, and it replaces O(k) with O(lg k) if the gap is larger.

However, by this point we are far, far down an optimization hole: profile, and determine if it is worth it before proceeding this way.

---

Another approach on sorted arrays is to presume that `std::lower_bound` is written optimally (on random access iterators).  Use an output iterator that throws an exception if written to.  Return true iff you catch that exception, false otherwise.

(the optimizations above -- pick one and bin search the other, and exponential advance searching -- may be legal for a `std::set_intersection`.)

---

I think the use of 3 algorithms is important.  Set intersection testing where one side is much smaller that the other is probably common: the extreme case of one element on one side, and many on the other is very well known (as a search).

A naive 'double linear' search gives you up to linear performance in that common case.  By detecting the assymmetry between sides, you can switch over to 'linear in small, log in large' at an opportune point, and have the much better performance in those cases.  O(n+m) vs O(m lg n) -- if m < O(n/lg n) the second beats the first.  If m is a constant, then we get O(n) vs O(lg n) -- which includes the edge case of 'use function to find if a single element is in some large collection'.

Comment: Interesting and fully informative answer. Just one gripe - can we change those `auto&&` declarations (for `rend` and `lend`) to `const auto&` please?

Comment: @RichardHodges Actually, looking at the range-for, it should be just `auto`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for (I figure mimicing that is best practices)

Comment: I think you want `const auto&` in the range-based-for just in case Lhs::value_type is expensive to copy (or non-copyable but moveable).

Comment: @RichardHodges `for(auto&& x:blah)` just does the right thing, so I use it without thought as a default.  And ` const` is so many more characters than `&`!  All remaining non-ref `auto` are copies of iterators, and if you have expensive iterators to copy you are doing it wrong.  ;)

Comment: But it means that x is mutable, which means maintainers of your loop have more latitude for error.

Comment: Nice answer, but your claim that O(m lg n) beats O(n+m) if m < O(n/lg n) is wrong: with the m < O(n/lg n) assumption, both O(m lg n) and O(n+m) simplify to the same thing, namely O(n).  Maybe you meant "If m is O(lg n), then O(m lg n) becomes O(lg^2 n) while O(n+m) becomes O(n), so the first beats the second".

Comment: @j_random `<` not `<=`.  If the growth rate of `m` is anything strictly less than the growth rate of `n/lgn`, then `m lg n` is asymptotically faster than `m+n`, if you want it in more words.

Comment: @j_random cont'd: And the growth rate being strictly less means, with a tad more rigor, `O(f(m))` is a strict subset of `O(n/lgn)`, where `O(f(x))` is used as notation for tye set of functions asymptotically bounded by `k f(x)` for some fixed `k`.  But `<` seemed easier to understand, and conventionally means the same in this context.

Comment: I see now, thanks.  Haven't seen that notation before, but it makes sense, and here allows a more general statement to made than the one I suggested.

Comment: [Never ever use exception for control flow!](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#why-not-exceptions)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following template function if the inputs are sorted:

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
bool intersect(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (*first1 < *first2) {
            ++first1;
            continue;
        } 
        if (*first2 < *first1) {
            ++first2;
            continue;
        } 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[] = {3, 4};
    int c[] = {4};
    std::cout << intersect(a, a + 3, b, b + 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << intersect(b, b + 2, c, c + 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << intersect(a, a + 3, c, c + 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
1
1
0
```

This function has complexity `O(n + m)` where `n`, `m` are input sizes. But if one input is very small to the other (n << m for example), it's better to check each of the `n` elements with binary search if it belongs to the other input. This gives `O(n * log(m))` time.

```
#include <algorithm>
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
/**
 *  When input1 is much smaller that input2
 */
bool intersect(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2) {
    while (first1 != last1)
        if (std::binary_search(first2, last2, *first1++))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is O(n+m).  You can write an O(n lg m) or O(m lg n) version instead if you have the containers (ie, a fast `find`), which (if one collection is massively larger than the other) can be faster.

Comment: Two containers of doubles.  One contains nothing but `+inf`.  The other contains 2 million doubles (all below `+inf`).  Your code does 2 million increments.  If the first container contained a bunch of negative numbers, then `+inf`, and the second a bunch of positive numbers, you would iterate over *every* element of both collections.  At *best* it does `min(n,m)` operations, but at worst it does `n+m` operations.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor No, it isn't. Consider `{1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`.

Comment: @T.C.: Either way, `O(n+m)` is smaller than `O(n*log(m))`.

Comment: @Bill let `n` = 1, and `m` = 1 billion.  O(n+m)=1 billion and 1.  O(n lg m)=30.  When, exactly, is 1000000001 smaller than 30 again?

Comment: @Yakk: In which case both are `O(1)`, because everything is a constant.

Comment: @Yakk: Either way, I encourage you to write up an answer with what you think is the better solution!

Comment: for sorted arrays (in which case it is cheap to iterate over every element) using std::lower_bound would still be faster. For std::set() above code is bad.

Comment: @ExcessPhase: Would you mind writing that up as an answer? Perhaps with some code implementing it? Perhaps with whatever assumptions you are making about the input? I personally don't see how you are going to use `std::lower_bound` and have a runtime better than `O(n*m)`.

Comment: @Yakk: That kind of misses the point of a Big-O complexity analysis. Plot the functions as n and m grow, and you should see that, as `n` and `m` both get large, `n+m` is strictly less than `n*log(m)`. `n*log(m)` solution may be faster in many cases, but not as far as Big-O complexity is concerned.

Comment: @AndyG fix n as 1 -- the case where you are asking "is there an element in another set".  Have m grow without bound.  In this case, `O(n+m)` dominates `O(n lg m)`.  For *any* fixed n as m grows, `O(n+m)` dominates `O(n lg m)`.  Only if **both** n and m grow is `O(n+m)` dominated by both `O(n lg m)` and `O(m lg n)`.  The point of multi-variable complexity analysis is that sometimes some values don't grow, while other constants do grow, and sometimes the rate of growth (between variables) isn't linear. If you force all variables to grow linearly, there is no point in multi-variable complexity.

Comment: @bill I explained your misunderstanding both here, and in an appendix to my answer.  Is it clear?

Comment: @Yakk: I think your answer is great! I haven't read your new edits, but I liked the initial explanation. I was an extra big fan of the use of `std::set::lower_bound`. I didn't realize that there was an `O(log n)` version of that available to sets and maps!

Comment: @Yakk: Agreed, thanks for the clarification. I think it would be clearer to say the algorithm for the case you propose is actually `O(lg m)` because `n` is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you can encode sets of numbers in a single memory word. For example, you could encode the set `{0,2,3,6,7}` in the memory word: `...00000011001101`. The rule is: the bit at position `i` (reading from right to left) is up, if and only if the number `i` is in the set.

Now if you have two sets, encoded in the memory words `a` and `b`, you can perform the intersection using the bitwise operator `&`.

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
int intersection = a & b;
int union = a | b;  // bonus
```

The good thing of this style, is that the intersection ( union, complementation ) is performed in one cpu instruction (I don't know if this is the correct term).

You could use more than one memory word, if you need to handle numbers that are greater than the number of bits of a memory word. Normally, I use an array of memory words.

If you want handle negative numbers, just use two arrays, one for negative numbers, and one for positive numbers.

The bad thing of this method, is that it works only with integers.

Comment: This might work with more than just integers, at least if we open the problem up to include probabilistic solutions. For example, one could hash the elements (which might be, eg, arbitrary strings) to determine which bit(s) to set, similar to a Bloom Filter. I've been thinking along these lines recently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a binary_search

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool overlap(const std::set<int>& s1, const std::set<int>& s2)
{
    for( const auto& i : s1) {
        if(std::binary_search(s2.begin(), s2.end(), i))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s1 {1, 2, 3};
    std::set<int> s2 {3, 4, 5, 6};

    std::cout << overlap(s1, s2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Wow, you had 2 sets already and you still managed to come up with a quadratic algorithm. `std::set` iterators are BidirictionalIterators, not RandomAccessIterators, `std::binary_search` doesn't make any sense. Just use `s2.count(i)`.